# Reseting password issue in Node.js with JWT

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I am facing an issue with reseting password when users forgetting their passwords.

So lets say my Frontend is published in IP say *12.12.12.12*

And my Backend services are running in *12.12.12.12:3000/api*

So a user is forgetting the password and clicks on forget-password button which calls the

following service:

```
POST - 12.12.12.12:3000/api/forgotpassword 
body: email address
```

After controlling the email, a link like this:

```
GET - 12.12.12.12:3000/api/resetpassword?token={token}
```

is sent to provided email.

So the problem starts now. How would you open the frontend when this link is clicked?If the token is not expired and valid.

Is it a good idea to use redirect in here? lets say I redirect to reset password page like:

```
12.12.12.12/resetpassword
```

But in here how I add the token at the end? otherwise everyone will have access to this page.

Hope I managed to explain the issue.

One last issue is

```
res.redirect(/resetpassword) ---> 12.12.12.12:3000/api/resetpassword (doesn't open page)
```

Answer (score 0):

the back-end url is not going to be exposed to user, you just send front-end password recovery page url and pass a token as get parameter.

reset page without parameter can be used to request recovery email and page with get parameter can be used to check the token with back-end to authenticate user and show it field.